# Yii2 call 2 functions on change of a dropdown

Tags: ajax, get, return, onchange, yii2

I have several dropdown imputs and on change of any of them I wanna a value to be offered for a textbox.
I have a code that i placed on each of my dropdown's and it works perfect for me:

```
<?= $form->field($model4, 'prevoditelj')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(
            \app\models\Prevoditelj::find()->orderBy('idprevoditelj')->asArray()->all(),
            'idprevoditelj',
            'naziv'
        ),['onchange'=>'
            $.get( "'.Url::base().'/index.php?r=zadatak/trosak&id='.$model->projekt.'_"+$("#'.Html::getInputId($model3, 'usluga').'").val()+"_"+$("#'.Html::getInputId($model3, 'dodatak').'").val()+"_"+$("#'.Html::getInputId($model3, 'obr_jedinica').'").val()+"_"+$("#'.Html::getInputId($model4, 'prevoditelj').'").val(), function( data ) {
                  $( "#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'trosak').'" ).val( data );
                });
                '])  ?>
```

in a controller I have:

```
public function actionCijena($id){
        $sve=explode("_",$id);//0 - projekt_id, 1 - usluga, 2 - dodatak/jez_kombinacija, 3 - obr_jedinica
        $projekt = Projekt::findone($sve[0]);
        $klijent = Klijent::findone($projekt['klijent']);

        $cjenik_klijent = CjenikKlijent::find()
            ->asArray()
            ->where('klijent = :id and usluga = :usluga_id and obr_jedinica = :obr_jedinica and jez_kombinacija = :jez_kombinacija and valuta = :valuta',
                ['id'=>$klijent['idklijent'],'usluga_id'=>$sve[1],'obr_jedinica'=>$sve[3],'jez_kombinacija'=>$sve[2],'valuta'=>$klijent['valuta']])
            ->all();
        //ako nema, gledaj opci cjenik
        if($cjenik_klijent==array()){
            $cjenik_klijent = CjenikOpci::find()
                ->asArray()
                ->where('usluga = :usluga_id and obr_jedinica = :obr_jedinica and jez_kombinacija = :jez_kombinacija and valuta = :valuta',
                    ['usluga_id'=>$sve[1],'obr_jedinica'=>$sve[3],'jez_kombinacija'=>$sve[2],'valuta'=>$klijent['valuta']])
                ->all();
        }
        return $cjenik_klijent[0]['cijena'];

}
```

The problem I have is that now I wanna add another calculated value to another textbox. but it needs to trigger on the same dropdown's. Unfortunately Get can't return an array so I need to split it up into 2 functions, but how do I call 2 of them?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to find a solution in returning 2 values in 1 string and then exploding them in jquery. Don't know why I didn't think of that sooner.